# How to remove empty spaces and omit the rows that has those empty spaces in R

Tags: r, janitor

[image]

So I tried to use df <- remove_empty(df, which=c("rows","cols"), cutoff = 1). It did not remove any of it even though there are empty slots in the data. Not sure what I did wrong or what I need to do to change, to make it remove the row entirely.

[image]

The results remained the same, as the blank spaces are still there and have yet to be omitted.

Comment: Hi KKNg, if you could run dput(head(df)), and edit your question to add the result, that would be great thanks!

Comment: try complete.cases(.)? https://statisticsglobe.com/remove-rows-with-na-using-dplyr-package-in-r#example-1-remove-rows-with-na-using-naomit-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example data.frame, which has empty strings (and some NA's).

```
> dat
    V1   V2 V3 V4 V5
1    A    A  1  6 11
2    B    B  2  7 12
3            3  8 13
4            4  9 14
5 <NA> <NA>  5 10 15
```

First, you want to `replace` the empty strings with `NA`'s and assign it back to `dat[]`,

```
> dat[] <- lapply(dat, \(x) replace(x, x  %in% "", NA))
> dat
    V1   V2 V3 V4 V5
1    A    A  1  6 11
2    B    B  2  7 12
3 <NA> <NA>  3  8 13
4 <NA> <NA>  4  9 14
5 <NA> <NA>  5 10 15
```

then subset the rows with`complete.cases`.

```
> dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat), ]
> dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  A  A  1  6 11
2  B  B  2  7 12
```

In one step:

```
> dat |> lapply(\(x) replace(x, x  %in% "", NA)) |> data.frame() |> {\(.) .[complete.cases(.), ]}()
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  A  A  1  6 11
2  B  B  2  7 12
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "", "", NA), V2 = c("A", "B", 
"", "", NA), V3 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), V4 = c("6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10"), V5 = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr`solution is this:

```
dat %>%
   # convert "" to `NA`:
   mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., ""))) %>%
   # remove any rows with `NA`:
   filter(!if_any(everything(), is.na))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  A  A  1  6 11
2  B  B  2  7 12
```

Thanks to jay.sf for the toy data:

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "", "", NA), V2 = c("A", "B", 
"", "", NA), V3 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), V4 = c("6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10"), V5 = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```